# Python Faker Phone Number Formatting

Tags: python, faker

I recently started working with Faker because of its ability to localize data to various regions. When trying to generate localized phone numbers, I realized that there are a variety of formats for the phone numbers as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxxJa.png). I was wondering whether it would be possible for all the generated phone numbers to be formatted like this: (+91 ##########), where regardless of the country code, it remained constant. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, `Faker` doesn't have a built-in function to do this.

**You have two options.**

Write functions yourself, for example:

```
def fake_phone_number(fake: Faker) -> str:
    return f'+91 {fake.msisdn()[3:]}'
```

```
from faker import Faker

def main():
    fake = Faker()
    print(fake_phone_number(fake))
```

Or create an appropriate provider and suggest adding it: https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/communityproviders.html

Python src [MSISDN](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/providers/faker.providers.phone_number.html#faker.providers.phone_number.Provider.msisdn).
What is [MSISDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSISDN).

**Or**

```
from faker import Faker
from faker.providers.phone_number import Provider


class IndiaPhoneNumberProvider(Provider):
    """
    A Provider for phone number.
    """

    def india_phone_number(self):
        return f'+91 {self.msisdn()[3:]}'


def main():
    fake = Faker()
    fake.add_provider(IndiaPhoneNumberProvider)
    print(fake.india_phone_number())
```

Comment: So this means that I would have to manually format each of 20 countries that my code would generate data for?

Comment: Not. Please expand your question with sample code to understand how you are using Faker.

Answer (score 3):

You can use faker's [hindi Indian provider](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/locales/hi_IN.html#faker.providers.phone_number.hi_IN.Provider.phone_number), it will generate most of the numbers with +91, but not all:

Code sample with `faker` and `factoryboy.Faker`:

```py
import factory
from faker import Faker

fake = Faker(locale="hi_IN")

fake.phone_number()

# with factory-boy's faker
class New(factory.DictFactory):

    phone = factory.Faker("phone_number", locale="hi_IN")

New()
```

Usage result:

```
print(fake.phone_number())
>> +91 9018742635
print(New())
>> {'phone': '+91 1489998444'}
```

If you want to ensure that every number has a +91, you need to tweak with `factoryboy` or wrap `fake.phone_number` with a parsing function.

A neat solution could be using a library called [phonenumbers](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers/tree/dev/python) like this:

```py
import phonenumbers
from faker import Faker

fake = Faker(locale="hi_IN")
number = fake.phone_number()
num_obj = phonenumbers.parse(number, "IN")
interanational_IN_number = phonenumbers.format_number(num_obj, phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL)
print(interanational_IN_number)
```

This should work most of the time, except with numbers starting with `091` - they should have two leading zero to be identified properly (0091), fix that corner case, and you should be good to go.